# Python associative array?

Tags: python, regex, perl

I did this in Perl, but how do you the same in python?

Example:

```
my %lineBuffer; #with a "%" sign

$linebuffer; #to call it indiviadually
```

This is what im thinking about doing in python.

linebuffer[ ]

to use a scalar I would do?

lineBuffer[result.group(1)]

Comment: You're going to have to explain what it does in Perl for people to explain if there's any Python equivalent.

Comment: It doesn't do much at all in Perl. `my %linebuffer` declares a hash (or dictionary) variable. `$linebuffer` is a completely separate scalar variable of the same name. I suspect the OP meant `$linebuffer{KEY}` which is the syntax to access an individual value from the hash.

Comment: @davorg You are absolutely right. It doesn't make sense to give it negative feedback to my question if you don't understand the question. You get it right davorg. $linebuffer{KEY}. So how do I do that in python?

Comment: Actually, "question is unclear" is one of the three canonical reasons for voting a question down - the others being "not useful" and "no research effort".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Python has them, though it calls them "dictionaries"; see [§5.8 "Mapping Types — `dict`" in the Python v2.7.2 documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict).

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for [`dict`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict). It creates a dictionary that allows you to access values in the collection with a key.